# Swift UIScrollView : keyboard doesn't dismiss interactively

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to dismiss the keyboard interactively, but my code is not working. I don't know why.
When I try the keyboard dismiss mode `onDrag` it is working fine and there is no need of any more code for that. 
Here is my code :

```
  import UIKit

    class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
        @IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false;
            scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.Interactive
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }



        @IBAction func LoginTapped(sender: AnyObject) 
{
              //here my code which is running 
        }
        func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return true
        }



       override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

         scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.Interactive
        }
    }
```

Here are screenshots of the simulator

[image]

Please take a look and if possible let me know where the error is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code. This will end editing when you tap anywhere on the screen.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //Looks for single or multiple taps. 
    var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

//Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
func DismissKeyboard(){
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: where i call the func dismissKeyboard

Comment: it;s called through the action in the tap UITapGesturerecogniser

Comment: Paste the code and it'll work. In detail explained, the tap gesture recogniser dismisses the keyboard by calling the action. The action just ends editing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78675/discussion-between-subhash-sharma-and-julian).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i finally solved it !

For me the Julian's solution didn't worked so i had to do it as it is :

Set a TapGestureRecognizer in your Storyboard and then an Outlet in your ViewController

```
@IBOutlet var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!
```

Then set an IBAction in your ViewController

```
@IBAction func DismissKeyboard(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
 self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

add these lines to your viewDidLoad method

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
 super.viewDidLoad()
 self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

and its should work

Hope that will help !

Answer (score -2):

The below code will work on all the components in the UIView for all the UITextField

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
for (UIView * txt in self.view.subviews){
    if ([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [txt isFirstResponder]) {
        [txt resignFirstResponder];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is your answer in swift ??

Comment: its the logic...u just need to figure out how to convert code in swift.