# Swift, how to convert an existing uiview to uiscrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a storyboard with just one view at the moment but i needed to add 5 more textfields. So i like to enable the vertical scroll. I thought i just had to change the class of the viewcontroller from UIView to UIScrollView:

[image]

Besides changes the class what else should i do so i can enable vertical scroll for this view??
Only thing i have in viewDidLoad()

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Set date to today
    let today = dateToday()
    dateInvoice.text = today
}
```

edit
ok i got the scrolling part working, but the hide/dismiss keyboard part doesn't work anymore. How do i dismiss the keyboard if a user clicks outside a textfield in scrollview

```
    //HIDE KEYBOARD
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
//END HIDE KEYBOARD
```

Edit 2:
I found a workable solution thanks to:
[Swift UIScrollView : keyboard doesn't dismiss interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434467/swift-uiscrollview-keyboard-doesnt-dismiss-interactively)

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Select your textfields and then In menu:

> Editor->Embed in->Scroll view

Then make the scrollview the right size and if you're using autolayout add the needed constraints.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just magically turn a UIView into a UIScrollView. Either delete the UIView and replace it by a scroll view, or else (easier) keep the UIView and drag a scroll view into it (and pin it on all four sides).

Comment: i put all my form elements in a scroll view (within the UIView) and pinned all 4 sides, but the magic didn't happen. What code should i add? And how can i trigger the UIscrollView as the following stopped working `  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }`

Comment: sorry matt, no i am a swift newbie, watch a bunch of tutorials. But can't recall the uiscrollview ones. Going back to the tutorials it is

Comment: It's all about the `contentSize`. Might help to read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html

Comment: Ok i got the scroller part working, but could you point me in the right direction for the hide key board part which doesn't work in the View>View>Scroll View part?

Comment: Drag a new scroll view into the existing ui view? or drag the existing ui view into the scroll view?